# Disable ssh password authentication on High Sierra

Tags: high-sierra, ssh

I want to disable password auth - ie keys only - on SSH. I've done this many times on Linux variants, and some searching here suggests it's the same on Mac, ie:

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Then add/edit:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

However, this seems to have no effect - ie I can still log in with a password. Is there any different trick to do this on High Sierra?

Comment: You have to edit the ssh.plist.  This will require disabling SIP. Editing it, reloading it via launchctl, then reenabling SIP.

Comment: Especially UsePAM has to be set to no. The settings of the following 4yo sshd_config should still work in 10.13: [SSH config that is password less](https://gist.github.com/MarioRicalde/746eefe5d5debbcda124)

Comment: @Allan I can confirm that you don't. I successfully disabled password auth in High Sierra (10.13.5) by editing _only_ `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` (I set the `PermitRootLogin`, `PasswordAuthentication`, `ChallengeResponseAuthentication`, and `UsePAM` options all to `no`); SIP has never been disabled on this particular Mac.

Answer (score 18):

To prevent authentication without a public key, search for each of these in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, uncomment them, and set them to 'no':

```
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM no
```

To restart sshd (which is required to have it reread the config file), use

```bsh
sudo launchctl stop com.openssh.sshd
sudo launchctl start com.openssh.sshd
```

PS: Please be aware that macOS tends to overwrite `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` with each minor update. Starting with Monterey you can put your definitions in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/000-local.conf` to avoid this.

Comment: Works also on Big Sur 11.6 Thanks.

Comment: My original answer only required setting PasswordAuthentication and UsePAM to no. Is it really necessary to also set ChallengeResponseAuthentication to no? What changed?

Comment: @coolaj86 What does `ChallengeResponseAuthentication` add?

Comment: @nohillside For macOS specifically, quite possibly nothing, but for ssh in general ChallengeResponseAuthentication refers to password authentication - so if you disable PAM but don't disable the other then it's still possible to login via password.

Comment: Putting it into `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/000-local.conf` on Monterey is an excellent idea. By my testing, config files with lower numbers override options set in files with higher numbers, so 000 (as opposed to 999) is indeed the best choice of number for this file.

Answer (score 5):

As it was said in klanomath's comment disabling only these lines won't work.

```
PermitRootLogin no
PasswordAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
```

To disable password login you need to edit UsePAM line as well.

```
UsePAM no
```

Answer (score 3):

klanomath's comment

> Especially UsePAM has to be set to no. The settings of the following 4yo sshd_config should still work in 10.13: [SSH config that is password less](https://gist.github.com/MarioRicalde/746eefe5d5debbcda124) – klanomath 2 hours ago

Seems to work. Never had to do that on Linux systems. Many thanks!